Filament multiselect form save
I am trying to implement filament admin panel for a existing project. I would like to implement multiselect.
I've conducted tests trying to select multiple and only 1. When I remove the "multiple" option and enter only 1, it works perfectly. However, when I change to "multiple" and select multiple items, it behaves as if the field doesn't exist. I explored the possibility of using a pivot table, but I couldn't save the selections within the pivot table.
I want save like this:
Table structure is as below.


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Tournament</td>
    <td>Athlets</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10;21;43</td>
  </tr>



or pivot table


<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Tournament</td>
        <td>Athlets</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>32</td>
      </tr>



My Table Equipes:


public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('equipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('atleta_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('competicoe_id');
            $table
                ->foreign('atleta_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('atletas')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table
            ->foreign('competicoe_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('competicoes')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }



My Model:
public function atletas()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Atleta::class, 'atleta_id');
}

public function competicoes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Competicoe::class, 'competicoe_id');
}

My EquipesResource:
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\Select::make('competicoe_id')
                ->label('Competição')
                ->relationship(name: 'competicoes', titleAttribute: 'titulo')
                ->searchable()
                ->preload()
                ->required(),
            Forms\Components\Select::make('atleta_id')
                ->label('Atletas')
                ->relationship(name: 'atletas', titleAttribute: 'nome')
                ->searchable()
                ->multiple()
                ->preload()
                ->required(),
        ]);

When i try save athlet not show multiple, i select like a image and get error



When you using mutiple

These options are returned in JSON format

and it save JSON if column is string
